# The meaning of "haven_labelled" in R

Tags: r

I inputted in R "class(abc$q01)" and then received "haven_labelled". What is the meaning of "haven_labelled"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard because I am just a R beginner and I cannot upload the source code.

Comment: You could provide the code which reads in your data set, if it's e.g. .dta, .sav, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `class` created when we either load foreign data  (SPSS, Stata, SAS) with `haven` functions i.e. `read_sav`, `read_dta`, `read_sas` (in that order) or specifically use `labelled`

```
library(haven)
s1 <- labelled(c("M", "M", "F"), c(Male = "M", Female = "F"))
```

Now check the `class

```
> class(s1)
[1] "haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "character"
```

---

According to `?labelled`

> A labelled vector is a common data structure in other statistical environments, allowing you to assign text labels to specific values. This class makes it possible to import such labelled vectors in to R without loss of fidelity. T

Comment: Also, in RStudio when you open a labelled `data.frame` you see the colum name as well as its label below in the column header.